# Why can't I access my DB on Heroku?

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I created a java app, connected to a PostgreSQL DB.
I deployed the DB on Heroku.

I can access the DB when using my app on localhost, but if I deploy my app on Heroku, I get the message : ***nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet***

All my DB table names are lowercase.

I also tried to modify config vars (DATABASE_URL) on Heroku, but I can't, I get an error : ***Item could not be updated:
Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL.***

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution.

Problem was that I previously created a PostgreSQL DB, but when creating a java app, Heroku also creates a PostgreSQL DB, and that created a conflict.

So, I redeployed my app on another Heroku pipeline, and now, it works fine.